# What does "Townsend quintile" mean?

Tags: cardiology, cardiovascular-disease, terminology

Can anyone tell me what does "Townsend quintile" mean exactly?

I am trying to use [this cardiovascular risk assessment](http://www.jbs3risk.com/JBS3Risk.swf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Townsend deprivation score" measures socio-economic status, and has five categories, hence you are being asked for your quintile. The scale is 1-5, and it [incorporates the variables](http://www.restore.ac.uk/geo-refer/36229dtuks00y19810000.php)

- car ownership
- house ownership
- unemployment
- overcrowding of the household

Since it needs to be standardized you can't just calculate it for yourself. 2001 Townsend scores for the UK can be found at the [UK census website](https://census.ukdataservice.ac.uk/get-data/related/deprivation). It seems to be occasionally used for risk assessments like in your link.